# How does this memoize function 'remember' stuff?

Tags: javascript, memoization

Consider this `memoize` function from this source: https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/

```
function memoize(func) {
  var memo = {};
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  return function() {
    var args = slice.call(arguments);

    if (args in memo)
      return memo[args];
    else
      return (memo[args] = func.apply(this, args));
  }
}
```

And then consider defining, for example, a function that returns the square of any number, which makes use of this function:

```
var square = memoize(function(num) {
  return num * num; 
}
```

Here's what I don't understand: everytime you call this `square` function, it would appear that you are calling `memoize` again, which redeclares the `memo` variable. How do the values in this `memo` variable persist across different calls of this function?

Comment: `everytime you call this square function, it would appear that you are calling memoize again` Why do you think that?

Comment: @SLaks, you're absolutely right. I don't know why I assumed that. I get it now, thanks.

Comment: @DouglasTylerGordon Sarcasm? Or do you really get it now? I can try to explain it more as well but if you truly understand it there is no need...

Comment: @War10ck, no sarcasm! Sorry if it came off that way! I realized I was making a silly assumption without actually understanding what it means for a function to return another function. Should I delete this question? What's the protocol if a mere comment solved it for you?